# how to set datasource properties dynamically

Tags: grails, datasource

I am using Grails and as my project's requirement I want to connect to databases as per users requirement. So I have to take the DB credentials like username,password,URL from user. How can I connect to their databases by setting these values in datasource at run time. Is there any way that I can set these values dynamically?

Comment: Are you wanting a data source per individual user or just for a user to reconfigure the single data source used by the entire application? That's not clear in your question.

Comment: I have my own mysql database.I want to connect to users database and fetch its all records and save it in my database.for this I want it's credentials.I am using multiple datasources 1.my own DB  2.User's DB.

Answer (score 0):

I will explain the concept and leave the implementation up to you. Be aware, this isn't exactly simple and does require you to do some research into the details, but if you are willing to do so, you can accomplish this.

The basic concept here is that each data source in your application is defined as a Spring bean. This is the default behavior of any Grails application. As such, you can replace a bean with a newly defined one. In your case you will want to do this with your second data source. The bean name is determined by how you have it named in your `DataSources.groovy`.

Take a look at the [Spring](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.4.x/guide/spring.html) section of the Grails documentation where it shows some examples of configuring a data source. The same concept will apply in your case. Just be sure you use the correct bean name and that you also call the destroy/close method of the existing bean before you replace it.

Depending on how you implement the replacement (and if you use a `GenericBeanDefinition` or not) you may want to use `grailsApplication.mainContext.registerBeanDefinition(beanName, beanDefinition)`.

As I stated, this can be done, but you are going to have to learn a bit about the internals of Spring and bean definitions, as well as the API to build and manipulate them at run time.

Hope this helps get you started.